# Faster App Engine Development Datastore Alternative

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is there a way to use a real database(SQLite, Mysql, or even some non-relational one) as  datastore for development, instead of memory/file datastore that is provided.

I saw few projects, GAE-SQLite(did not seem to be working) and one tip about accessing production datastore using remote api (still pretty slow for large datasets).

Comment: Why? What advantage would you gain?

Comment: Easier development, development datastore shipped with SDK is too slow to experiment even with more than few hundreds of entities.

Comment: Apart from my answer below, I did not experience the significant slowdowns you mention with lots of entities.

Comment: With about 40k entities my development server consumes about 2GB of RAM bringing my entire computer to a halt. Is there anyway we can use the real online datastore with the development server?

Comment: With a few thousand entities, each with a single property, my dev server takes so long to call `Entity.query` that I just leave it and get on with something else for a while. I've taken to running a clean up in every test, just to prevent anything accumulating, so now every test takes ages :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB works great for that. You will need:

- The MongoDB stub: http://github.com/mongodb/mongo-appengine-connector
- MongoDB: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Downloads
- Some code to set it up like:

code:

```
import datastore_mongo_stub

os.environ['APPLICATION_ID'] = 'test'

datastore = datastore_mongo_stub.DatastoreMongoStub(
    os.environ['APPLICATION_ID'], 'woot', '', require_indexes=False)

apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy.RegisterStub('datastore_v3', datastore)
```

But if you're looking for truly faster development (like I was) the datastore is actually not the issue as much is the single threaded web server. [I tried to replace it with spawning](http://bit.ly/Za4rM)  but that was a little too hard. You could also try to set up [TyphoonAE](http://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/) which will mimic the appengine stack with open alternatives.

Be aware that if you do any of these, you might lose some of the exact behavior the current tools provide, meaning that if you deploy you could get results you didn't expect. In other words; make sure you know what you're doing :-)

Comment: Koen thanks, that is the closest thing to what I was looking for. Unfortunately admin console is useless since schema introspection is not implemented. I am looking for a gui tool that I can use to view data at least.

Comment: Ok, then a few other pointers. There is a guy who started a SQLite stub: http://blog.appenginefan.com/search/label/SQLite. I'm nut sure if he ever finished it, but maybe you can get it to work. There should be enough GUI browsers for SQLLite. But keep in mind the data model is not very browsable as it's mimicking a key-value store. Then again, I have done a sh*tload of appengine development and never really needed the data browser, but maybe that's a style thing. Good luck :-)

Comment: Oh, and thinking about it, the databrowser should actually work with any stub as it uses the normal datastore api. So if it doesn't work out of the box it should not be hard to fix.

Answer (score 2):

The Google App Engine SDK for Python now bundles support for SQLite. See the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver?csw=1#Python_Using_the_Datastore) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

[bdbdatastore](http://arachnid.github.com/bdbdatastore/) is an alternative datastore backend that's considerably better than the one built in to the development server, although the datastore is far from being the only problem with the dev server when it comes to handling large applications.

Comment: unfortunately it is pretty outdated, I tried to apply the patch to SDK 1.3 but the patch is pretty big to be fixed without understanding all the underlying code.