# Local App Engine datastore is slow once loaded up, any suggestions?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've loaded up a local datastore with 40,000+ entries.  Unfortunately, 
recalling any data from it at all is very slow on my fairly new 
Macbook Pro.  Any suggestions on speeding things up, short of buying a 
new piece of hardware?

Answer (score 0):

[This question addresses a few alternatives you could try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112950/faster-app-engine-development-datastore-alternative).

For speeding up unit testing, you can set the datastore to stay in memory only, and not flush to disk.  This may not help you if you need 40,000 entities to meaningfully test your system of course :)

Comment: "For speeding up unit testing, you can set the datastore to stay in memory only, and not flush to disk."  Any idea how to do this?